# how check all of my file copy correctly by batch file?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch-file, xcopy, cut-and-paste

I have a batch file that copy all the files from src place to dest place.

I used xcopy command.

Now I want to make sure all of my file copy correctly and delete all the files in src folder, do you have any idea?

I dont know is there any command for delete the folder with all the files and folder inside it?

please advise me....

my source folder has below structure

```
> root | 
>         [sub folder1]
>         |
>         filex.s
>         filei.z 
>         [sub folder2]
>         |
>         filep.a
>         fileq.q
>         [sub folder3]
>         |
>         filex.s
>         filei.z
>         filsi.w 
> file1.xx 
> file2.cc 
> file3.ss
```

Comment: You could consider using the MOVE command instead of XCOPY

Comment: xcopy much more reliable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del /s` would delete from subdirectories.
`fc`     would compare two files.

`dir/s/b /a-d > list.bat` would dump all file names to a text file.

You could use Notepad++'s Macros to mass edit the text file to FC each file.

You could use a batch file to do a sort of for/each over the files doing the same thing.

Comment: del /s do not delete the folders for folders what should I do? del just delete all files, I want remove folder also...for comparison do u have any code?

Comment: RD /s /q  is much more better :)